# create user in react native expo adding extra information

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, expo

I am currently doing a react native course and I need to create a user with the following conditions (name, cuit, date of birth, address, location, cell phone and email)

We saw firebase but I really got stuck and I don't know where to start, I was searching the internet and reading the documentation and I ran out of places to go to ask.

since apparently firebase only lets you add little information in the firebase authentication.

and i haven't found much so far

Comment: Welcome to SO. The Firebase documentation is a great resource to start with. In fact, there's a whole section about [Users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users) and some great tips like this one - "You cannot add other properties to the user object directly; **instead, you can store the additional properties in any other storage services, like Firestore.**"

Comment: Would it be like having the authentication for the users and in a secondary base (firestore) with the extra information?

Comment: Yes to your first question. Users are stored in Firebase via Authentication and that function (all lower case) is not a valid function see [Create Users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#create_a_user). If you have other questions they should be posted as a separate question to keep focus on what was asked. Be sure to read the documentation and attempt some code before posting.

Comment: Thank you very much for guiding me and helping me so far.

Currently here I have my data

`const [user, useStateUser] = useState({
    Name: "",
    cuil: "",
    nPartner: "",
    birth: "",
    home: "",
    location: "",
    cell phone: "",
    email: "",
  });`

Is it possible to use createUserWithEmailAndPassword with the current useState or should I create one for the user, one for the password and the rest for the extra information?

Comment: although in any case the partner number (nPartner) would be the user and the password (cuil)

Comment: The process is generally to create the user with the email address and password which establishes the user in Firebase and assigns them a user id (uid). Once you have the uid, you would then write additional information to, for example, a `/users` node with the entry having a key of the uid and then whatever additional data you want to store. A LOT of this is covered in the documentation and there are dozens, if not hundreds, of examples here on SO about how to do that task.